# indexing multi-level index dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, multi-index

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'dts':['1/1/2000','1/1/2000','1/1/2000','1/2/2000', '1/3/2000', '1/3/2000'],
                            'product':['A', 'B', 'A','A', 'A','B'],
                            'value':[1,2,2,3,6,1]})
a =mydf.groupby(['dts','product']).sum()
a
Out[1]: 
                  value
dts      product       
1/1/2000 A            3
         B            2
1/2/2000 A            3
1/3/2000 A            6
         B            1
```

`a.loc[('1/1/2000','A'),]` gives the first row.

```
  a.loc[('1/1/2000','A'),]
    Out[2]: 
    value    3
    Name: (1/1/2000, A), dtype: int64
```

but why `a.loc[['1/1/2000','A'],]` give the second row for B as well? The only difference is the bracket

```
a.loc[['1/1/2000','A'],]
Out[3]: 
                  value
dts      product       
1/1/2000 A            3
         B            2
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace 'A' with something completely different:

```
a.loc[['1/1/2000','XYZZZ'],]

                  value
dts      product       
1/1/2000 A            3
         B            2
```

Now, repeat this with the tuple:

```
a.loc[('1/1/2000','XYZZZ'),]
```

And this is what you get:

```
KeyError: ('1/1/2000', 'XYZZZ')
```

When specified as a list, pandas will attempt to index on the first level only. "1/1/2000" is present in the first level, and all records associated with it are returned.

When specified as a tuple, it assumes the tuple values for all levels, and when it does not find it, a KeyError is raised. When it does find it, just that row is returned.

Comment: I don't think this behavior should be intentional.

Comment: I'd guess the reason is that tuples are hashable and thus easily comparable. Lists are not, which forces either an error being raised (which would be counterintuitive given that everything in pandas slicing uses `[` `]`) or iterating through the list. Maybe using the first element is a solution to prioritize performance